# How do Remote Desktop Applications work on Android?

Tags: android, remote-access

This question may seem low-quality but Im trying to understand what concepts should I read/libraries should I use to make such an application. If there's a better place to post this question, please let me know.

I wish to add **remote desktop access** to my **Android app**, so that I can watch and control my laptop screen and execute commands (shell scripts maybe?) on my laptop (from my phone). I should be able to connect this app with any RD clients on Ubuntu (Remmina).

I have a decent understanding of Android development, but no idea on how to make Android apps which talk to other machines. It'd be great if I could get some guidance on what Android libraries should I use to achieve this objective.